# Android app transfers string to server using php

Tags: php, android

In my project,I need to transfer image and string to server(server side uses php).I completed uploading images to server.So the only question is how can I send string to server.Can anyone tell me how to do it?

Comment: pinpoint a specific area where you have problem

Comment: Sorry,I don't know anything about this.So I have to study from zero.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is some code that should point you in the correct direction.

First, use something like this on your application side:

**Java:**

```
// generate your params:
String yourString = "This is the string you want to send";
List<NameValuePair> nameValuePairs = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();
nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("your_string", yourString));

// send them on their way
try {
    DefaultHttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient();
    HttpPost httpPost = new HttpPost("http://xyz/your_php_script.php");
    httpPost.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(nameValueParams));  
    HttpResponse httpResponse = httpClient.execute(httpPost);
    HttpEntity httpEntity = httpResponse.getEntity();   
} catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
} catch (ClientProtocolException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
} catch (IOException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

And pick it up with something like this on your server side (http://xyz/your_php_script.php):

**PHP:**

```
<?php
    if (isset($_POST['your_string']) && $_POST['your_string'] != '') {
        $your_string = $_POST['your_string'];
        echo 'received the string: ' . $your_string;
    } else {
        echo 'empty';
    }
?>
```

Edit, per your comment:

It is more complicated because you have to use a `OutputStream` and `BufferedWriter`, so I don't know why my solution won't work for you.  Using Google, I found the following answers that may help you:

- https://stackoverflow.com/a/13486223/586859
- [Android HTTPUrlConnection POST](https://stackoverflow.com/q/10759782/586859)
- http://digitallibraryworld.com/?p=189

Comment: thans a lot,but can you tell me how to do this using HttpURLConnection?

Comment: @kevin320 I updated my answer to point you in the right direction.